# nested function cant find itself in Typescript

Tags: html, typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following code:

```
//Main Entry Point.
start() {
    this.init();
    this.gameLoop();
}

//Init, runs only once.
init() {
    let initalEntity1: Entity = new Entity(10, 10, Gender.female);
    let initalEntity2: Entity = new Entity(60, 60, Gender.male);
    console.log("There are " + this.Entities.length + " Items in the entities Array")
    this.Entities.push(initalEntity1, initalEntity2);
    console.log("There are " + this.Entities.length + " Items in the entities Array")
}

gameLoop() {
    console.log("Performing a Game Loop");
    requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop);

    //MAIN LOOP THROUGH ENTITIES
    for (let i in this.Entities) {
            this.Render.drawEntitysToScreen(this.Entities[i].EntityPosition, this.Entities[i].gender);
        }
}
```

It enters into `start()` fine, and also performs all of the `init()` functionality. it them proceeds onto `gameloop()` which it will run once, however the line `requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop);` which is ment to retrigger the function to be called as a Canvas frame is causing the following error:

`TypeError: this is undefined`

trying to `requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);` but it causes the typescript compiler to get upset...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to how `this` binding works in javascript. The way by which you are passing `this.gameLoop` to `requestAnimationFrame` is essentially passing an unbound `gameLoop` function, and so when it is called, it has lost reference to its `this`.

There are a number of possible solutions to this problem:

1. You can bind `this.gameLoop` to `this` inside of the class constructor, like so:

   ```
   constructor() {
     this.gameLoop = this.gameLoop.bind(this);
   }
   ```
2. You can bind `this.gameLoop` to `this` as part of the `gameLoop` method definition. Rather than defining `gameLoop` like

   ```
   gameLoop() {
   ```

   If you instead use

   ```
   gameLoop = () => {
   ```

   it will be automatically bound to `this`. This is a property of using the fat arrow for function declarations: it automatically performs binding to the `this` that exists at the function declaration.
3. You can change how you pass `gameLoop` to `requestAnimationFrame`:

   ```
   requestAnimationFrame(() => this.gameLoop());
   ```

   This again takes advantage of the automatic `this` binding performed by the arrow function, but instead of doing it as part of the class method declaration you can simply do it lazily at the time you need it to be bound.

   Note, however, that doing it this way does mean that a new function will be created each time `gameLoop` is called.

Comment: Your first example doesn't actually do anything. The function returned from bind is not assigned anywhere. `this.gameLoop = this.gameLoop.bind(this)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `this.gameLoop()` within `start`, the value for `this` inside `gameLoop`'s body will be the class `gameLoop` belongs to, because you call `gameLoop` as a property of `this` (the class).

When you pass a function reference its value for `this` might be anything when the function is called from somewhere else.

---

**Solution 1 | Using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**

`bind` the value for `this` as you give the function to `requestAnimationFrame`. By doing this you explicitly say:

*Let the argument to `bind` be `this` inside any call to `gameLoop`, regardless of how it is called, or where it is called from.*

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop.bind(this));
```

Note that bind returns you a *new function*, so the original `gameLoop` function that is still a property of your class remains unchanged.

---

**Solution 2 | Using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**

Define an arrow function to eventually execute the call to `gameLoop` instead of `requestAnimationFrame`. The `this` value within arrow functions is static, and is inherited from the execution context enclosing the function declaration.

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.gameLoop());
```